# ios - Disabling key or hiding keyboard in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I want to disable the return key on the keyboard of my app while I am performing a certain task, and then enable it again after the task is finished. Is this possible? If not can I disable the entire keyboard or just hide it for this period of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hiding keyboard you can do [textField/textView resignFirstResponder]; for that text textfield or text view. Also you can call `[self.view endEditing:YES];` if you want to hide keyboard at any stage of app.

Comment: how long will [self.view endEditing:YES]; disable it for?

Comment: [self.view endEditing:YES]; will hide key board if keyboard is open.

Answer (score 0):

To hide Keyboard use

```
[textField resignFirstResponder]
```

and to Show Keyboard use

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder]
```